# How to make python code to ready content of some directory and add it in list?

Tags: python

I have this code ...

```
Fontpath='/usr/share/fonts'

config.plugins.RR.fonts = ConfigSelection(default = "nmsbd", choices = [
                ("nmsbd", "nmsbd"),
                ("analog", "analog"),
                ("setrixHD", "setrixHD"),
                ("army-digital", "army-digital"),
                ("ForgottenFuturistShadow", "ForgottenFuturistShadow"),
                ])
self.list.append(getConfigListEntry(_("Select Style of Font"), config.plugins.RR.fonts))

if config.plugins.RR.fonts.value == 'nmsbd':
    addFont('%s/nmsbd.ttf' % Fontpath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
elif config.plugins.RR.fonts.value == 'analog':
    addFont('%s/analog.ttf' % Fontpath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
elif config.plugins.RR.fonts.value == 'setrixHD':
    addFont('%s/setrixHD.ttf' % Fontpath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
elif config.plugins.RR.fonts.value == 'army-digital':
    addFont('%s/army-digital.ttf' % Fontpath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
elif config.plugins.RR.fonts.value == 'ForgottenFuturistShadow':
    addFont('%s/ForgottenFuturistShadow.ttf' % Fontpath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
```

I need to change the code to make possible to read all fonts from (Fontpath) and set the add it in config list ...

as like this ..

```
Fontpath='/usr/share/fonts' ### read all fonts
config.plugins.RR.fonts = ConfigSelection("Add the result here")
addFont(config.plugins.RR.fonts.value, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
```

Comment: Do you have a list of font values that you want to add? You can just loop over those files with `glob`. Are you wanting to refactor your if and elif part, or are you wanting to make the list of choices dynamic?

Comment: Yes I need dynamic code ... for Example if I have 5 fonts the all fonts should be show in list and If I add more files of fonts should be automatically show in list if I open the code again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you need to make your choices a variable. In this case, you won't view the list in your python code after you determine it, it isn't auto-generated python code, it's a dynamically generated list based on the present filepaths.

```
import pathlib
fontPaths = '/usr/share/fonts'

font_types = pathlib.Path(fontPaths).glob('*.ttf')

# this creates your choices list of tuples
font_choices = [(str(f.stem), str(f.stem)) for f in font_types]

config.plugins.RR.fonts = ConfigSelection(default = "nmsbd", choices = font_choices)

# I am making the second parameter an underscore because it is identical to the
#  first parameter.
for choice, _ in font_choices:
    if config.plugins.RR.fonts.value == choice:
        addFont('%s/%s.ttf' % (fontPaths, choice), 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
```

Then, to refactor the if/elif part, you can note that all of them are directly from your list of choices in the top. You can iterate over choices a variable and iterate.

Comment: but How can I appear it on plugin menu ?!! this code important config.plugins.RR.fonts = ConfigSelection(default = "nmsbd", choices = [
                ("nmsbd", "nmsbd"),
                ("analog", "analog"),
                ("setrixHD", "setrixHD"),
                ("army-digital", "army-digital"),
                ("ForgottenFuturistShadow", "ForgottenFuturistShadow"),
                ])
self.list.append(getConfigListEntry(_("Select Style of Font"), config.plugins.RR.fonts))

Comment: config.plugins.RR.fonts = ConfigSelection(default = "nmsbd", choices = [])

Comment: You just assign the choices to be your dynamically created font_choices. Check update?

Comment: I have got error no model name pathlib and I fix be os.path.join then other error with invalid syntax (addFont(f'{Fontpath}/{choice}.ttf', 'RSQFont', 100, 1)) and fix be remove (f) .. But this error how to solve it ?!! str object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: run `pip install pathlib`

Comment: I'm using the code in plugin for E2 device not on pc machin

Comment: I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... I figured out the correct code looks like

```
appPath = '/usr/share'
fontsPath = os.path.join(appPath + '/fonts')
defaultFont = os.path.join(fontsPath, 'nmsbd.ttf')

fonts = []
try:
    if os.path.exists(fontsPath):
        for fontName in os.listdir(fontsPath):
            fontNamePath = os.path.join(fontsPath, fontName)
            fontName = fontName[:-4]
            fonts.append((fontNamePath, fontName))
except:
    print('Error in gettings fonts')



config.plugins.RR.font = ConfigSelection(default=defaultFont, choices=fonts)

try:
        fontPath = config.plugins.RR.font.value
        addFont(fontPath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
except:
        try:
            fontPath = PLUGIN_PATH + '/fonts/nmsbd.ttf'
            addFont(fontPath, 'RSQFont', 100, 1)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('addfont', ex)
```